# Create a Google Form (or similar) that verifies Student ID before submission

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-forms

Context:
I teach at a university with mostly monolingual, English-speaking teachers, and students with mostly Russian and Kazakh names.

I want to create a simple form (like this https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1zo0vSfrH-xIosENy1wVjOd_VvPL5LL6UX6g4VqIPFn0/viewform ) that would keep track of reports of plagiarism on a Google Sheet (like this https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h2nAvCq31xumi4SvjMvWWp8RR7ppJ_NtLCiuvrLqVkc/edit?usp=sharing )

Having the English speaking teachers type in Russian and Kazakh names would likely lead to mistakes. There are too many students at the university to choose them from a drop-down menu, and would be too many teachers and courses to create separate Google Forms for all of them, or to use Google's branching page choices (it would require creating hundreds of pages). So I would like instructors to be able to type in the Student ID # and their own Instructor ID #, and then have ***some*** way to verify that they have typed that information in correctly (so we don't have the wrong students being penalized, or penalties that don't get assigned to any student at all).

Questions:
1. Is there any possible way (via scripting, an add-on, etc.) to have Google Forms take the Student ID from Page 1, then look up the student's name on the Student Info tab of the Google Sheet and insert it into the text field on the second page of the Google form, so the instructor can verify it's the correct student? (Or any other technique anyone can think of that would allow a Google Form user to verify that they had entered the correct data, or help manage the massive number of choices of students in a university of several thousand students.)

2. If (as I'm afraid), there is no way to do it with Google Forms, can anyone suggest a Form creation platform that *would* do something like this, and that would integrate with Google Sheets or something similar?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google Forms has no way to do data validation from data outside of the Form.  A script could validate the data **after** the Form submission, and send out an email if there was an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to doing it differently I'd go this route...

1) Use a short answer box and allow edits to answers.
2) Put the onSubmit() trigger into the sheet. When a submission comes in, send a follow up email to the person with the ID that they typed and the student name that it corresponds to. Let them know that no action is required if that is correct. If it isn't correct, they should edit their response with the edit response link which you can get using getEditResponseUrl(). I'd call it done right here and only worry about additional features if they are needed. It isn't as ideal as verifying at the time but would get the same thing done for people that can't keep their IDs straight. :-)
3) But... if you have people that keep messing up and they don't fix their issues or whatever, add a link in the email to confirm that the entry is accurate. If it isn't then a weekly/daily task runs that deletes any entries that haven't been confirmed and are older than Y days.
4) Alternately, instead of verifying what they type, give them drop down lists made up of a combination of student ID and name. I'd have multiple lists, depending on the number of active students. One or many though, make a script in the sheet that updates the dropdowns in the form either on edit or by manually running the script, either from a menu item or by attaching it to an icon on the page where the IDs/names are at. They should see 12345 - Joe Smith as the option and can find the right one if that student name doesn't match the ID they thought they should use. 
I have a script like #4 that I use to populate a form with updated products whenever the list changes. I tied it to a big red button JPG to help the end users remember to run it when they change something, as a menu option didn't work and running every time there was an edit was too much.
If you list of students/IDs also includes the teachers/classes/etc you could even do custom forms for each staff member that uses the form that only populates their students. Not sure how many staff you have so that might not be practical. Though again, once you have the script and the data is accurate, updates are a single click.

Comment: How do you connect a script to the Next button?

Comment: You will need to start a new thread for each time that you run into an issue so that the title coorresponds to the question and answer content. You can start with a google search for "google form scripts" and work with something that you find.

Comment: One of the things you will do is install triggers so that you can use these https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit On the first page if you have ID (student) and ID (professor) you can set it so that when they are edited/changed you run the script that validates that entry. So it isn't really running when they click next so much as it is running when they finish that blank. That would also allow you to do more than just the 2 IDs on the first page BTW.  Good luck!

Comment: Keep in mind though that SO isn't a coding service. So when you dig into the code bits you should post the code that you have tried. What is occurring that shouldn't / what isn't occurring that should / error messages and the line they have occurred on and anything that you tried to resolve it. Everyone is happy to help others learn to fish but we generally don't just hand out a fish. :-)

Comment: There is no "built-in" way to assign a script to the "Next" button.  There is a difference between what is possible, and what is practical.

Comment: The onEdit() trigger that @Rodger refers to is not available for Forms.

To solve this precise issue at our Institution I have used JQuery autocomplete in a custom form, hosted on Google sites, served using HTMLService.

Comment: yup, I pulled that out. You could do it on submit but not on edit. :(

Comment: Thanks @samScholefield, I think this issue (lack of the onEdit() function on Forms) was what was messing up my attempts. I have no budget for this, so I wouldn't want to use Google sites. The university has its own intranet, but the IT department is unreliable and we don't want to give them control of this. I am thinking a cheesy workaround would be to give each instructor their own tab they can edit on the Google sheet and just use VLOOKUP on one cell to display the name based on the ID they put in the other cell. Otherwise, I don't know how I would do this in a (free) form. :(

Comment: I edited the answer. If you are open to a slightly different process, that could work for you in a way that is a bit prettier than with a vlookup on a sheet.

Comment: @BeauBranson I assumed because you were using Google and mentioned students that you were leveraging the Google Apps For Education (GAFE) suite, which is completely free for educational institutions - might be something you want to look into.

Comment: @Beau Branson If you are still working in this contact me at ednelson@sbcglobal.net and I will share what I have developed. Thanks, Ed

Comment: Based on what @Ed Nelson shared with me, it looks like Formfuse ay allow me to achieve what I was looking for:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXUsW6VRQak